# POSTing link information PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, input, submit

So, apparently, I can't use `<a>` to send PHP `POST` requests to another page. I've read somewhere (I think here at SO) that I can use an appropriately CSS'd form submit button to pretend something's a link and then `POST` with it, but I'm not sure how to do it - all the ways I've found so far are limited to sending a button's 'value' parameter (which AFAIK is its label), but I want to send *other* information than that.

- I want something that looks like a link to `POST` information that's not in the text of the PHP page it redirects to.
- And I want to have multiple "links/buttons" on a page and want each of them to `POST` a different thing.
- I also want that different thing would be something *other* than the button's text, and I also don't know what kind of buttons there will have been on the previous page (they were automatically generated by PHP).

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with hidden inputs. Namely, input type="hidden". In the form action, you'd want to place the url you need to submit to.

As for making the submit look like a link, you'd need to use a bit of CSS

css

```
input[type="button"], input[type="button"]:focus, input[type="button"]:active,  
button, button:focus, button:active {
/* Remove all decorations to look like normal text */
background: none;
border: none;
display: inline;
font: inherit;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
outline: none;
outline-offset: 0;
/* Additional styles to look like a link */
color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "foo" value = "foo">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "bar" value = "bar">
  <button type = "submit">Click me!</button>
</form>
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGQNgm)

Comment: I added a thing to the question I forgot to mention.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho — None of your edits invalidate this answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't tell me how to make the different buttons submit different things given that I don't know in advance which or how many buttons exist.

Comment: If you want to submit different things with different buttons then just use a separate form for each of those with their respective values.

Comment: Using various <button> instead of input with comma separated values seems to do the trick.